# Best way to add run parallel proccesses in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I have a telegram bot in aiogram and I need to run few tasks of checking google sheets in background. Here is my current code:

```
async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(loop1())
    asyncio.create_task(loop2())
    asyncio.create_task(loop3())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Code in each function looks like this:

```
async def loop1():
    while True:
        # Iterating over data
        time.sleep(PAUSE)
```

Code runs in single thread VPS so eventually loops "pausing" and waiting for each other and don't run in parallel. Is there a better way to run this background tasks?

Comment: I don't think that's your real code.  You can't make an asyncio task from a sync function, which is what you're showing here.  That would be a runtime error.  To create a task you need a coroutine, which means a function declared with `async def`.  Also, the `time.sleep` function blocks the current thread, which in general you don't want to do in asyncio.  Use `await asyncio.sleep(PAUSE)` instead.

Comment: @PaulCornelius Yeah, sorry,  there is an async keyword before each function

Comment: @lisa.smith Maybe change `time.sleep(PAUSE)` to `await asyncio.sleep(PAUSE)` ?